# Inverse of a skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

For $a, x, y, z \in \mathbb R$, let $$M= \left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    \cos(a)  & \sin(a) \, x & \sin(a)\,  y & \sin(a) \, z \\
    -\sin(a) \, x & \cos(a) & \sin(a) \,z & -\sin(a)\, y \\
   -\sin(a) \, y & -\sin(a) \, z & \cos(a) & \sin(a) \, x \\
  -\sin(a) \, z & \sin(a) \, y & -\sin(a)\, x & \cos(a)
  \end{array}
\right).$$ 
Without doing much calculation, why the matrix $M-I_4$ is invertible and why its inverse is given $$(M-I_4)^{-1}=\,\frac{-1}{2} I_{4} - \frac{\cot(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} )}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} A,$$
where $A$ is the skew-symmetric matrix given by 
$$A=\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    0 & x & y &  z \\
    -x & 0 & z & -y \\
    -y & -z & 0 & x \\
    -z & y & -x & 0
  \end{array}
\right).$$
Thank you in advance

Comment: With 919 credits you should know that this is not a homework solution platform. What have you done so far on the problem?

Comment: Note that $M = \cos(a)I + \sin(a)A$ and hence $M-I = (\cos(a)-1)I+\sin(a)A$. So, $M-I$ is definitely not invertible if $a\in S:=\{2k\pi : k\in\mathbb Z\}$. Let $a\notin S$. Then $M-I$ is invertible iff $A-\frac{1-\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}I$ is invertible. Since $A$ as a skew-symmetric matrix does not have real eigenvalues other than possibly zero, $M-I$ is invertible for $a\notin S$.

Comment: If you're comfortable with [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), then it may be useful to observe that $M = \cos(a) I + \sin(a) A$, and that
$$
A = x \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} \otimes \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0} + \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}\otimes\pmatrix{y&z\\z&-y}
$$

Comment: Another hunch: I think that $A^2$ is a multiple of the identity, but I am too lazy to verify that this is the case.

Comment: You can use Schur complements to get to the inverse. Or just check whether the given inverse $K$ matches $K(M-I) = I$. ;-)

Comment: That works. However, I'm wondering what the author of the question had in mind when he said "without doing much calculation".

Comment: I think checking the given inverse is what the author was looking for

Comment: The "inverse" as it stands is false anyway because it does not depend on $a$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Actually, you were right, sorry. We have $-A^2 = (x^2+y^2+z^2)I_4$.

Comment: @amsmath perfect, then we can use the minimal polynomial of $M$ to compute the inverse

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Correct. From $(A-z)(A+z) = A^2-z^2 = -r^2-z^2$ we conclude that $(A-z)^{-1} = -(r^2+z^2)^{-1}(A+z)$. :-)

Comment: @Z. Alfata Could you react to our 3 answers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof of the first part (inversibility of $M-I_4$)
and a computation of the inverse (though I do not get a result in the form of yours).

One obtains an efficient simplification by using half-angle formulas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) :

$$\cos(a)=\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \ \  \text{and} \ \ \sin(a)=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

Let $N=M-I_4$.

All entries in matrix $N$ have a common factor $\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}$. Therefore we can set

$$N=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}P \ \ \text{with} \ \  
P:=\begin{bmatrix}-t&x&y&z\\-x&-t&z&-y\\-y&-z&-t&x\\-z&y&-x&-t\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, an equivalent issue is to show the invertibility of $P$.

Please note that $P=A-tI_4$ with matrix $A$ as you have defined it.

It turns out that the determinant of $P$ is very compact :

$$\det(P)=(t^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2\tag{1}$$

which is non-zero, excepted... exceptional cases $x=y=z=0$ and $t=0$ (the last case corresponding to angles $a=k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$). Set apart these cases, $P$ is always invertible.

Now, what is the inverse of $M-I$ ? The inverse of $P$, considered as a quaternion (see remark 1 below) is

$$P^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix}-t&-x&-y&-z\\x&-t&-z&y\\y&z&-t&-x\\z&-y&x&-t\end{bmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{n}(-A-tI_4)\tag{2}$$

$$\text{with }n:=t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2\tag{3}$$

(one can easily check (2) by multiplying $P$ and $P^{-1}$).

Therefore, as $M-I_4=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}P=\sin(a)P$, using (2) and (3), we get

$$(M-I_4)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\sin(a)}P^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{n\sin(a)}(A-tI_4)\tag{4}$$

which is different from your formula (as it has been remarked, this formula needs to depend on $a$).

**Remarks :**

1) It is not surprizing to get formula (1) : it is to be related to the $4 \times 4$ matrix representation of **quaternions** (see paragraph "Matrix representation" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) and their so-called "norm". By the way, I wouldn't be that surprised that your issue comes from quaternionic representations...

2) Using (1) with $t=0$, we get 
$$\det(A)=(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2\tag{2}$$

3) Formula (1) has to be connected to the so-called Pfaffian. If we have had to compute the determinant of a skew-symmetric matrix of **even order**, it is good to know that there exists a formula as a square of a polynomial expression in its entries called its associated Pfaffian. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian where you will find the following formula for order $4$ :

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}0&a&b&c\\-a&0&d&e\\-b&-d&0&f\\-c&-e&-f&0\end{bmatrix}=(af-be+dc)^2$$

Comment: The invertibility of $M-I$ was already shown in the comments (in a few lines).

Comment: @amsmath I agree, but the interesting thing is to "unearth" connections, here with quaternions, or as Omnomnomnom a connection with Kronecker products

Comment: I am sure you can find lots of other connections. However, OP asked for a simple and short reasoning. Well, anyways. Maybe you started your answer before I was writing my short comment.

Comment: It's true that I hadn't paid attention to your calculation which is indeed a rather quick way to get the inversibility by using eigenvalues. What I wanted to say is that we can help people in different ways by showing them different approaches. I am reluctant at considering "short reasoning" as a good criteria for  solutions ranking, but it's only an opinion.

Comment: Good point, Jean Marie. Actually, I agree. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach which is relatively light on computation.

As in the comments, we observe that $A^2 = -(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)I$.  It follows that any rational function of $A$ can be written in the form $p I + q A$ for some $p,q$.  In other words, there necessarily exist numbers $p,q$ such that
$$
(M-I)^{-1} = ([\cos(a) - 1]I + \sin(a)A)^{-1} = p I + q A
$$
Now, expand the product $(M-I)(pI + qA),$ and solve for the $p$ and $q$ that cause this product to equal $I$.  In particular, we have
$$
(M - I)(pI + qA) = ([\cos(a) - 1]I + \sin(a)A)(pI + qA)\\
= p(\cos(a) - 1)I + (q[\cos(a) - 1] + p\sin(a))A + \sin(a)qA^2\\
= \left[p(\cos(a) - 1) - \sin(a)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)q \right]I +  \left[q(\cos(a) - 1) + p\sin(a)\right]A.
$$
Thus, it suffices to find $p,q$ that solve the system of equations
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
(\cos(a) - 1) &p &- &\sin(a)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)&q &= &1\\
\sin(a) &p &+ &(\cos(a) - 1)&q &= &0.
\end{array}
$$
Solving this system yields
$$
p = \frac{1 - \cos(a)}{D}, \quad q = \frac{\sin(a)}{D}
$$
where $D$ is the determinant of the coefficient matrix of this system, that is
$$
D = \sin^2(a)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (\cos(a) - 1)^2.
$$
I see no general way of simplifying the resulting expression.

Comment: I have a $+$ where you have a $-$ in the expression for $D$ (just before $(\cos(a)-1)^2$).

Comment: @amsmath you're right; I'll see if that leads to any simplifications

Comment: @amsmath it doesn't, unless we know that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ for instance

Comment: You should make the leading minus a plus in $D$. ;-) As to the simplification: yes, you're right. I don't see a way to make it easier either. Actually, I wonder how OP came up with their false formula...

Comment: @amsmath minus signs... my kryptonite, apparently

Comment: I think I make a minus/plus mistake every day. Hate it!

Answer (score 3):

$A$ has the form $A = \begin{pmatrix}J&L\\-L&J\end{pmatrix}$, where $JL+LJ = 0$, $J^2 = -x^2I$, and $L^2 = (y^2+z^2)I$. Therefore,
$$
A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}J&L\\-L&J\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}J&L\\-L&J\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}J^2-L^2&0\\0&J^2-L^2\end{pmatrix} = -r^2I_4,
$$
where $r := \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Hence, for $z\in\mathbb C$ we have $(A-z)(A+z) = A^2-z^2I = -(r^2+z^2)I$ and thus
$$
(A-z)^{-1} = -\frac{A+z}{r^2+z^2}.
$$
Now, as I wrote in the comments, we have $M-I = (\cos(a)-1)I + \sin(a)A$. So, for $a = 2k\pi$ the matrix $M-I$ is singular, whereas for $a=(2k+1)\pi$ we have $M-I = -2I$. If $a$ is not one of these values,
$$
(M-I)^{-1} = \left[\sin(a)\left(A - \frac{1-\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}\right)\right]^{-1} = \frac 1{\sin(a)}\cdot\frac{A+\alpha}{r^2+\alpha^2},
$$
where $\alpha = \frac{1-\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}$.

Comment: Presumably, $A + \alpha$ should be $A + \alpha I$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's the short form that's commonly used by people in spectral theory.

Comment: I have a little improved my answer ; our results look very similar. Nota : your $\alpha$ can be written $\cot(a/2)=(1-t^2)/(2t)$. The first time a cotangent is appearing...